# How to catch a URL from a tweet or string in PHP , used parse_url but it doesnt work

Tags: php, twitter, oembed

Ok , I would like to dynamically automatically parse URLS from tweets that update on my application automatically , I tried to parse them using parse_url function in PHP but it doesn't return what I expect .. I'd basically like to only catch the URL from the tweet..

Example : John McCain's most updated tweet says :

```
Must-read Jackson Diehl: "What the #Iraq war taught me about #Syria" http://t.co/7YHYQY6bW0
```

After using parse_url to catch the URL from that tweet , it returned this

```
array(2) { ["path"]=> string(35) "Must-read Jackson Diehl: "What the " ["fragment"]=> string(55) "Iraq war taught me about #Syria" http://t.co/7YHYQY6bW0" }
```

I'd basically like to only catch  `http://t.co/7YHYQY6bW0` or any other multiple urls inside the same tweet ... How can i do this in PHP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parse_url is for splitting off the pieces of a URL itself. You'll want to do something like preg_match_all since there could potentially be more than one URL in a tweet.

```
<?php
    $string = 'Must-read Jackson Diehl: "What the #Iraq war taught me about #Syria" http://t.co/7YHYQY6bW0';

    preg_match_all('!http[s]?://[^ ]+!',$string,$urls);

    print_r($urls);

?>
```